# Limit of the inverse of a sum

Tags: limits

So I cant really wrap my head around this limit. It is from https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2300. Let $N < \infty$, I want to show that:
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\sum_i^N\left(\sum_j^N e^{-tf(i,j)}\right)^{-1}=N
$$
knowing that $0\leq f(i,j)<\infty \quad \forall i,j$

I understand that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} e^{-t} = 0$ but I have trouble justifying that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\left(\sum_i^N e^{-tf(i)}\right)^{-1}$ is not even undefined.

Comment: It is false in general, take $f=0$ then the limit is $1$. What are the hypothesis on $f$ ?

Comment: @Tuvasbien From the paper's introduction: "Given a finite metric space $X$ with metric $d$ we define the spread $E_0(X)$ by$$E_0(X)=\sum_{x\in X}\frac1{\sum\limits_{x'\in X}e^{-d(x,x')}}"$$So presumably $f(i,j)=d(x,x')\ge0$, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $i\in[\![1,N]\!]$, then $f(i,j)>0$ for $j\neq i$ thus $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow +\infty}e^{-tf(i,j)}=0$. We then have
$$ \sum_{j=1}^N e^{-tf(i,j)}=1+\sum_{j\neq i}e^{-tf(i,j)}\underset{t\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}1 $$
Summing this for $i\in[\![1,N]\!]$ we get $$ \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\sum_{j=1}^N e^{-tf(i,j)}\right)^{-1}=N $$